# How do I capture response of form.submit without ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am integrating payment 3D to my phonegap javascript APP so there is no successURL and failURL because this is app not website

If i did this

```
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

It submit form successfully but I can not get response

If I do ajax call like this

```
 $.ajax( {
            type:'post',
            url:'https://sanalposprov.garanti.com.tr/servlet/gt3dengine',
            data:formData,
            processData: false,
            success:function(response) {
            .....
```

It give cors error because bank server only accept form post,it is not allow ajax call

what should I do ?

Comment: If the site does not allow CORS, you may be limited to making a proxy endpoint on your server that you call, that performs a web request to the secondary site from the server, and returns the response you want back to the client.

Comment: Can you give the exact cors error message you are seeing?